# How to safely bypass tabs in RegEx

Tags: regex, debugging

I'm using C to do my regular expressions. Things work except for when the input string contains tabs.

This is my RegEx I plug into the regcomp function:

```
(DROP).*(tcp).*([\\.0-9]+).*0\\.0\\.0\\.0.*dpt:([0-9]+)(.*)
```

Regcomp returned OK with no issues.

I then used the following string to do the matching with:

```
DROP\ttcp\t--\t202.153.39.52\t0.0.0.0/0\ttcp dpt:21
```

I'm using such string to simulate output of iptables because I want to make a program to see which IPs are already listed.

When I execute my program, I receive the following pieces of output after executing the RegEx where the first line is data from the first offset:

```
DROP   tcp     --      202.153.39.52   0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21
DROP
tcp
2
21
```

Everything is correct except the second-last value. It shows 2, but I expect it to be 202.153.39.52. and I used `([\\.0-9]+)` in my RegEx to try to specifically state I only want numbers and dots to match.

How do I fix my RegEx?

**UPDATE**

I then proceeded to use this RegEx instead in hopes I get each individual octet of the IP address

```
(DROP).*(tcp).*([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+).*(0\\.0\\.0\\.0).*dpt:([0-9]+)
```

This is my result:

```
DROP   tcp     --      202.153.39.52   0.0.0.0/0       tcp dpt:21
DROP
tcp
2
153
39
52
0.0.0.0
21
```

Now this means the first `([0-9]+)` isn't processing properly. I should receive a 202, not a 2. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do I need a special flag for any RegEx function?

Comment: So if your input string does not contain tabs, but instead say, a single space character in their place each, then it works as you expect it to?

Comment: I just discovered that I need to be more definite. I had to replace the second `.*` in the original RegEx with a `.*\\ ` to specifically accomodate for the leading space. After experimentation, it turned out what I thought were tabs were actually spaces.

Comment: Tabs or spaces doesn't matter, `.*` matches both--along with everything else.  If you switch to a non-greedy `.*?` (except the `.*` at the very end, in your first regex)  you should get the result you expect.  But I recommend [Gene's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35216057/20938), which completely eliminates the uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about the difference between regex syntax and that syntax encoded as a string (in languages like Java that don't have first class regexes).

Try something more robust and commonsense:

```
DROP\s+tcp\s+\S+\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+0\.0\.0\.0/0\s+tcp\s+dpt:(\d+)
```

This will capture the ip address and the port number only. Why would you want to capture a fixed string like `DROP`?

As a string, this is:

```
"DROP\\s+tcp\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})\\s+0\\.0\\.0\\.0/0\\s+tcp\\s+dpt:(\\d+)"
```

Use an online regex tester [like this one](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) for testing and to convert from regex to string automatically.